# Ckeditor when i add text the whole 'p' should be hilighted

Tags: ckeditor

When i write in a paragraph in ck editor i want it to highlight the whole of he current paragraph in different background.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change/add this:

FCKConfig.EnterMode = 'div' ;    // p | div | br
FCKConfig.ShiftEnterMode = 'br' ;   // p | div | br

in fckeditor.config.js